# Not Enough Disk Space Error during Maple installation

Tags: partitioning, software-installation

I am currently trying to install Maple (a math program) for ubuntu.

When I go through the installation process and get to the part where I am supposed to select the location for installation, it gives me an error saying

```
You do not have enough disk space to install Maple.
```

I'm sure this is incorrect because I just installed Ubuntu this morning.

Any suggestions?

---

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Can you give more specific system informations?

Comment: Just linked the info

Comment: Please add output of `df -h` to the end of your question.

Comment: Just added the output of df -h

Comment: Which partition are you trying to install to? Edit your question to include current-window-only screenshots of gparted, for both the sda and the sdb drives. Which drive is your boot device?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check which partition i'm trying to install to, and I'm also not sure how to check which drive is my boot device. This is my first time being exposed to linux

Comment: I don't see any `df -h` output in your question. The `lshw` isn't useful here.